# JQuery: Keyup, how do I prevent the default behavior of the arrow (up & down) and enter key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onkeyup, enter

**JavaScript (JQuery)**

```
$('input').keyup(function(e)
{
    var code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;

    switch(code)
    {
        case 38:
        break;

        case 40:
        break;

        case 13:
        break;

        default:
        return;
     }
 });
```

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="/">
<input type="text" name="text" />
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I have 2 problems:

1) The caret shouldn't move when I hit the **up** arrow key.

For example, in Chrome when I hit the up-key it moves the caret to the left. But I only have this problem in Chrome. It works fine in FF.

2) When I hit the **enter** key, I don't want the form to be submitted.

BTW, I want to get this to work with **keyup** and not **keypress**.

I'd appreciate any ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I don't think you can [`preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) (which is what you'd need to use to stop the browser from performing the default action for a key) on the `keyup` event - it is fired *after* the default event has already occurred. See [this page](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html) for more.

If you can, consider using the `keydown` instead.

As for stopping the form from submitting, you could bind to the [`submit` event](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) and `return false;` when the submit was not triggered by the submit button (see [jQuery: how to get which button was clicked upon form submission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721724/jquery-how-to-get-which-button-was-clicked-upon-form-submission) for how to determine this).

On the other hand, you could also bind to `keypress` for the form and when <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed, cancel submission the same way (untested code):

```
$('form').keypress(function(e){
    if(e.which === 13){
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: I know, but I was hoping there was another way to prevent the default behavior of the keyup function. But thanks!

Comment: @krysis Sorry, doesn't look like there is much you can do with `keyup`

Comment: Thank you, anyways! :) Maybe I'll get `keydown` to work for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: `$('form').keypress(function(e){
    if(e.which === 13){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});`

Comment: +1 I was trying to `preventDefault()` on KEYUP to prevent scrolling while certain elements had focus. KEYDOWN worked for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of break you could try return false or make it call a function and use http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

For example: `case 40: function(e) {e.preventDefault;}`

Also, `$('form').submit(function() {return false});` would stop submissions altogether, but I'm not sure that's what you're after?

Comment: I've already tried e.preventDefault, but it doesn't work for some reason. And I have no idea why. It only works when I use keydown / keypress.

Comment: @krysis None of the answers in their current form (making use of `keyup`) will work because `keyup` if fired *after* the default action is already done so you cannot `preventDefault()`. See my corrected answer.

Comment: also, `preventDefault` is a function, so should be `e.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent the form being submitted when the user presses enter you need to bind the submit function of your form and return false if the event trigger was the enter button being pressed.

for the Up/Down button press, use `e.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable method is a combination of `e.preventDefault()`, `e.stopPropagation()` and `return false`;

Here's what it might look like:

```
var override_keys = [13, 38, 40];

$('input').keyup(function(e){
  var code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;

  if ($.inArray(code, override_keys)) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
  }
});
```

Also, to prevent the form from being submitted with the enter key you should check the form's `submit` event:

```
$('#form').submit(function(e){
  var code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;

  if ($.inArray(code, override_keys)) {
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: the keyup event can't be prevented, take a look [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that you actually CAN stop the default for 'ENTER' while using keyup(); ... jQuery api writes about it themselves here: http://api.jquery.com/keyup/

Here's how you have to do:

```
$('textarea').keyup(function(e) {
   // your code here
}).keydown(function(e){
   // your e.which for ENTER.
});
```

Comment: That's not using `keyup` though - and that's the whole point. You're right - that code will work, but only because you're using `keydown` for suppressing the enter key. As other answers have stated here, you can't do this using `keyup` alone, as the event will already have been fired by then and you can't go back in time and suppress it.