# If I don't press write button, I want to show an alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload

I assign the element id "btn_submit" to write_ok button.

I wanted the following:

if I press write_ok button,
  do write,
else (if I do not press write_ok button)
  do alert message before page exit.

I don't know how can i find out which button was pressed.

I found this, but I cannot get it to work: [jQuery: how to get which button was clicked upon form submission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721724/jquery-how-to-get-which-button-was-clicked-upon-form-submission)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
    if ( #btn_submit was not pressed )
        return 'If you exit the page, you may lose your changes';
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var btn_submit_pressed = false;

  $(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
      if ( btn_submit_pressed )
          return 'If you want to exit page, you may lost your writing';
  });

  $('#btn_submit').click(function(){ btn_submit_pressed=true; });

</script>
```

Comment: WOW~!!! Great~!!! 

`<script type="text/javascript"> 
  var btn_submit_pressed = true; 
 
  $(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){ 
      if ( btn_submit_pressed ) 
          return 'If you want to exit page, you may lost your writing'; 
  }); 
 
  $('#btn_submit').click(function(){ btn_submit_pressed=false; }); 
 
</script> `

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce a variable:

```
var isSaved = true;  // at the beginning there's nothing unsaved
```

Whenever the user updates something, set:

```
isSaved = false;
```

When the user clicks submit, set:

```
isSaved = true;
```

Then in `beforeunload`, just check:

```
if(!isSaved) {
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. if i add variale, i must do many works.

Comment: @OpenCode: Not sure I understand. This should be pretty trivial; you shouldn't need to add more than these 4 lines of code.

Comment: i just want to do like this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721724/jquery-how-to-get-which-button-was-clicked-upon-form-submission

Comment: my test code is...`<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
    var val = $(#btn_submit).is('[clicked=true]');
    alert(val)
//    if ($("input[type=submit][clicked=true]").val())
//      return really want to exit page?';
});
</script>`

Answer (score 0):

Pawar's code is a big idea.
to compress and generize the code, #btn_submit changed to "input submit".

message in return is appear only IE not firefox, chrome.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  var btn_submit_pressed = true; 
  $(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){ 
  if ( btn_submit_pressed ) 
        return 'if you leave this page, chages will be lost.'; 
  }); 
  $('#btn_submit').click(function(){ btn_submit_pressed=false; }); 
</script>
```