# Formaction, formmethod, formenctype through jQuery submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, html, events

I want to know how to get the `formmethod`, `formaction`, `formenctype` or `formtarget`, when set in the `<input type="submit">` inside the form, on the `submit` event.

```html
<form action="/url" method="POST">
  ...
  <input type="submit" value="Action 1" formaction="/another-url">
  <input type="submit" value="Action 2" formmethod="PUT">
</form>
```

```js
 $(function(){
   $('form').bind('submit', function(){
     // how to get it here?
     // need to know if action1 or action2 was clicked, and if any of them have "form*" attributes
     return false;
   });
 });
```

They are explained in here http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/html5-forms-pt2.html#articlecontentAdobe_text_31

Since I'm creating a jQuery plugin, I have no idea of where this is going to be used, so it must be a one-size-fits-all solution. It seems that jQuery can't deal with it to provide a safe cross browser solution yet.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: how to get which button was clicked upon form submission?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721724/jquery-how-to-get-which-button-was-clicked-upon-form-submission)

Comment: updated my question, it's not a duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get formmethod and formaction from submit button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34326274/how-to-get-formmethod-and-formaction-from-submit-button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, but I don't know if it's crossbrowser:

```js
$('form').on('submit', function(event){
   var submit_button = event.originalEvent.explicitOriginalTarget;
   if (submit_button.attr('formaction')){
      // form action, enctype, etc
   }
   return false;
});
```

EDIT: this is only for Gecko, I'm searching for alternatives. Seems that IE has `event.srcElement`, but it isn't the same. `event.originalEvent.explicitOriginalTarget` is the way to go, but only works in Firefox, nor Chrome or IE have any ways to do it.

There isn't a cross browser way of doing this unless binding to the `submit` buttons (`<input type="submit">` and `<button type="submit">`), but that won't work for manually set up buttons that will do submits through Javascript, while binding "submit" it will work as intended

Answer (score 2):

I'm settling on this:

```
$('form > button[type="submit"]').bind('click', function() {
    this.parentNode.action = this.getAttribute('formaction');
});
```

This snippet assumes `button` is direct descendant of `form`, but could be easily expanded to be more general-purpose.

I think it's a flaw in the standards, and *real* form action should be accessible by JavaScript somehow, without ever touching the buttons or their values. As far as I can tell, it isn't possible without workarounds.