# Form Different Submit Action

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, submit

I have a form to showing a report, but I need 3 features which is `print to pdf`, `print to excel`, and also showing preview via html itself using `js`

This is the first condition that only for `pdf` and `excel` and work well for both.

**controller:**

```
respond_to do |format|
  if params[:print]
    format.html { redirect_to :action => "report", :format => "pdf", :start_period => params[:start_period], :end_period => params[:end_period], :warehouse => params[:warehouse] }
  elsif params[:excel]
    format.html { redirect_to :action => "report", :format => "xls", :start_period => params[:start_period], :end_period => params[:end_period], :warehouse => params[:warehouse] }
  else
    format.html
  end
end
```

**view:**

```
<%= form_tag(models_path, :method => "get") do %>
  <%= submit_tag "#{t 'pdf'}", :name => "print" %>
  <%= submit_tag "#{t 'excel'}", :name => "excel" %>
<% end %>
```

But when I start adding preview feature through `js`, it not error, but both submit button (pdf n excel) **pointing to js**.

**new controller**

```
respond_to do |format|
  if params[:print]
    format.html { redirect_to :action => "report", :format => "pdf", :start_period => params[:start_period], :end_period => params[:end_period], :warehouse => params[:warehouse] }
  elsif params[:excel]
    format.html { redirect_to :action => "report", :format => "xls", :start_period => params[:start_period], :end_period => params[:end_period], :warehouse => params[:warehouse] }
  else
    format.html
    format.js # NEW LINE
  end
end
```

**new view**

```
<%= form_tag(models_path, :method => "get", :id => "headers_search") do %>
  <%= submit_tag "#{t 'ep.submit'}", :name => nil, :remote => true %>
  <%= submit_tag "#{t 'pdf'}", :name => "print" %>
  <%= submit_tag "#{t 'excel'}", :name => "excel" %>
<%= end %>
```

`headers_search` is pointing on **application.js**

```
$.fn.ajaxFilter = function() {
  this.submit(function() {
    $.get(this.action, $(this).serialize(), null, "script");
  return false;
  });
}

$("#headers_search").ajaxFilter();
```

So, I confuse on where I did mistake.. I'm kind of rails newbie. Thanks

Comment: I think my `headers_search` cause that effect, yeah?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
if params[:name] == "print"
```

Answer (score 0):

The jquery `seralize()` method does not serialise submit buttons. See the docs at [Jquery - Serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/).  This means that when you submit the form via jquery, none of the submit buttons are included.

You need to edit the jquery submission to include which button was clicked for your code to work.

See the answer to the question at - [jQuery: how to get which button was clicked upon form submission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721724/jquery-how-to-get-which-button-was-clicked-upon-form-submission) on how to determine which button was pressed.