# Identify which asp.net submit button has been clicked in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have two asp buttons in my form in asp.
When I click on any of the submit buttons the function below is called which eventually calls callotherfunction().

```
  $("form").live("submit", function() { 
    callotherfunction();
});
```

I want to distinguish between the clicks and I want to run the callotherfunction(); only for 1 button.

These are my two submit buttons:

```
<asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Start Search" />      
<asp:Button ID="btn2" runat="server" OnClick="Button2_Click" Text="Export Data to Excel" />
```

i have already tried identifying the button click bny using the code:

```
$("input").click(function() { 
alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

I dont get any alert.
How should I go about the process.

Comment: Want to show your relevant rendered HTML? Your `$("input").click(function() {` should work fine.

Comment: yes Even I thought so.But it is giving me no alert and no error.Is there any other way to get the id of the submit button that is clicked?

Comment: Can you post the HTML, right now we can only speculate on why this isn't working.

Comment: live was deprecated in 1.7 and removed in 1.9. Do not use it. Instead learn to use `on()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: how to get which button was clicked upon form submission?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721724/jquery-how-to-get-which-button-was-clicked-upon-form-submission)

Comment: <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Start Search" />                                              
<asp:Button ID="btn2" runat="server" OnClick="Button2_Click" Text="Export Data to Excel" /> these are my two submit buttons

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#<%=btn1.ClientID %>").click(function() { ...});
```

something like this

Answer (score 0):

this code worked for me!

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input[id$='btn1']").click(function () {
            alert("button1");
        });
    });
```