# Error getting the id of the clicked button in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

HTML:

```
<form id="myForm" >
     <input id="oknovo" type="submit" value="OK & Novo" />
     <input id="okfechar" type="submit" value="OK & Fechar" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(event){
    var botao=$("input[type=submit][clicked=true]").id;
    alert(botao);
});
```

How do I identify which of the buttons was clicked to submit the form?

I've also checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721724/jquery-how-to-get-which-button-was-clicked-upon-form-submission)

And tried this:

```
var botao=$("input[type=submit][clicked=true]").val();
```

But I always get "undefined".

Comment: $("input[type=submit][clicked=true]").attr('id');

Comment: Same result, you may see a live example here:http://jsfiddle.net/nuno/3fJ3r/

Comment: If you are willing to submit the form to be handled in php, you can check it in php very simple. Therefore you would have to give the submitButtons each a name and can then check theire value in php...

Comment: @Martin I also want the browser to dismiss or reload the form for new input

Comment: Ok then you have to use one of the answers to catch the click with js. By the way if you are using jQuery why not take the id by normal $(...).attr('id'); function?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var buttonID;

$("#myForm input[type=submit]").on('click', function() {
    buttonID = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Update:

I've updated your code and added a little example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3fJ3r/12/). Seems to work ok now.

Comment: Thanks for defining buttonID outside the function ;-D

Comment: No matter where I define the variable, I can't get it to work.. http://jsfiddle.net/nuno/3fJ3r/4/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("input[type=submit]").click(function(event){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

A form is submitted, when you click the `input type="submit"`

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n8rWY/)

Comment: It seems to be working (http://jsfiddle.net/nuno/3fJ3r/1/). This will also submit the form, right? :-D

Comment: if you are just wanting the id you could use `this.id` and it would be better for performance

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.prop()` to get the id of clicked element

Try this:

```
$("input[type=submit]").click(function(event){
    alert($(this).prop('id'));
});
```