# populating a field value based on the button clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html form with a hidden field and 2 submit buttons. Based on what button in clicked ( trial or buy) I need to set the promo code field ( with "trial" as promo code for trial button and "buy "as promo code for  buy button.

I am not sure how I could read what button is clicked in java script. I have a java script already in place that is copying email ID into another field on hitting submit. I'd like integrate the java script with existing one.

HTML code:

```
<form>Email:
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <br>
    </label><input type ="hidden" name="retype-email">
    <br>

    <input type="hidden" name="PromoCode" value="" method="post">

    <input class="Orange_button" type="submit" value="Start my free trial"> 
    <input class="green_button" type="submit" value="Buy it now"> 
</form>
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x1bdgvyt/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the best solution is to manually track which button was clicked by subscribing to their "click" events.

**[Working Example here (jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/uybq5sk3/2/)**

#### HTML

```
<form>Email:
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <br>
        </label><input type ="hidden" name="retype-email">
    <br>

    <input id="promo-code" type="hidden" name="PromoCode" value="" method="post">

        <input class="Orange_button" type="submit" value="Start my free trial" data-code="trial"/> 
        <input class="green_button" type="submit" value="Buy it now" data-code="buy"/> 
</form>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
    $('[name="retype-email"]').val($('[name="email"]').val());
    var value = $("input[type=submit][clicked=true]").data("code");
    $("#promo-code").val(value);
    alert(value);
    e.preventDefault()
});

$("form input[type=submit]").click(function() {
    $("input[type=submit]", $(this).parents("form")).removeAttr("clicked");
    $(this).attr("clicked", "true");
});
```

Note that I added a [data attribute](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to the submit buttons so that we can store the code that should be added.

**source:** [jQuery: how to get which button was clicked upon form submission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721724/jquery-how-to-get-which-button-was-clicked-upon-form-submission)

Comment: It works fine in jsfiddle. But whrn I try it on my dev server, the variable 'value' doesnt not get the data-code.

Comment: Did you add the `data-code="trial"` and `data-code="buy"` attributes to the buttons?

Comment: Thanks. It was my mistake. I was adding it in in media queries that wasn't even being triggered. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

First, add 'data-type' (or whatever the name, most important is the prefix `data-`) to your inputs:

**HTML**

```
<input data-type="trial" class="Orange_button" type="submit" value="Start my free trial">
<input data-type="buy" class="green_button" type="submit" value="Buy it now">
```

Then, change a bit your javascript in order to grab the `data-type` value and populate your field with it:

**Javascript**

```
$('[type="submit"]').on('click', function(e) {
    // populate your duplicated 'email' field
    $('[name="retype-email"]').val($('[name="email"]').val());
    // populate your 'code' field : grab the data-type attribute added in your HTML
    $('[name="PromoCode"]').val($(this).data('type'));
    // finally, submit the form
    $('form').submit();
});
```

Quick warning: you should consider using IDs or classes instead of working with wide selectors like `[attr]`, it could be an issue if you have more than one form in your page (and it's a better practice anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
$('#usuario_form').submit(function(e){   
   console.log($('#'+e.originalEvent.submitter.id));
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

You can have access to OriginalEvent Submitter Id to identify wich button was clicked