# how is it possible to send data related to each button to php by using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I know that a code like this is used for sending data to php file without refreshing by using ajax, but this code only works for one form with some inputs, my problem is:
I have a web page that in it there are 5 buttons and each button is related to different input, I want to send data with ajax without refreshing,for example when I click on button 1, it sends its own inputs and when I click button n it sends its own data, how can I do that?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function () {

    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {

      e.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'led.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function () {
        }
      });

    });

  });
   </script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <form>
      <input type='hidden' name="key" value="on">
      <input name="key" type="submit" value="ON">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax POST example with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> " but this code only works for one form with some inputs "

Technically speaking, that will work with any form on the page. (as you are targeting the `form` tag)

If you want to target mutliple buttons and process them the same way add a class to them.

If you want to target seperate elements individually, add an id.

You then target classes as `$('.classname')` and ids as `$('#id')` notice the . and # (as with css selectors)

[**SEE LIVE EXAMPLE here**](http://jsfiddle.net/qacb0sb7/)

```js
$('.submit_to_a').parent('form').on('submit', function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'a.php',
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function() {}
  });

});


$('#gotob').parent('form').on('submit', function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'b.php',
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function() {}
  });

});

$('#gotoc').parent('form').on('submit', function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'c.php',
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function() {}
  });

});
```

```html
<form action="a.php">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <button type="submit" class="submit_to_a">goes to a</button>
</form>
<form action="a.php">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <button type="submit" class="submit_to_a">goes to a</button>
</form>
<form action="b.php">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <button type="submit" id="gotob">goes to b</button>
</form>
<form action="c.php">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <button type="submit" id="gotoc">goes to c</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have different form and form elements for each buttons. If so then this might help you.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
 $(function () {
    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {

      e.preventDefault();

      var formdata=$(this).serialize();

      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'led.php',
        data: formdata,
        success: function () {
        }
      });
    });
  });
   </script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <form>
      <input type='hidden' name="key" value="on">
      <input name="key" type="submit" value="ON">
    </form>
    <form>
      <input type='hidden' name="anotherkey" value="on">
      <input name="key" type="submit" value="ON">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

This will serialize the form element which you have clicked and send it to your PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out what button was clicked and decide which data to send:
(this is copied form [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5721762/536226))

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").submit(function() { 

    var val = $("input[type=submit][clicked=true]").val()

    // DO WORK

});

$("form input[type=submit]").click(function() {
    $("input[type=submit]", $(this).parents("form")).removeAttr("clicked");
    $(this).attr("clicked", "true");
});
```

But, I highly recommend using a different form for each set of data.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a unique id for each form you have, and your jquery will look like

```
$('#form_id').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    #your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form').on('submit', function (e) {

      e.preventDefault();
      $inputs = $(this).serialize(),

      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'led.php',
        data: $inputs,
        success: function () {
        }
      });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, **You have two inputs with same name "key". Always Give it a different names. And input type submit does not require a name**

Give  an id to each form. Then use it like this

```
$('#form_id').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
   Your code here
});
```