# Get value of either of the two submit button based on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

i have a html form with two submit buttons and two textboxes

here's the form

```
<form action="domains.php#searchdomain" method="post" name="m_domain"
      onsubmit = "return primalValidate()">
 <table class="dataTable" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" id="" style="text-align:center; margin-top:0px; border-left:1px solid #ddd; border-right:1px solid #ddd; border-top:1px solid #ddd;">
          <tr>
            <td align="left" colspan="2"><div id="display_message" <?php echo $sstyle; ?>><?php echo $dis_msg; ?></div></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="left">Search Domain</td>
            <td align="left" style="display:none;" id="apply_text">Replace Selected Domains With</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td align="center"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                  <td><input class="input_field" name="search_domain" id="search_domain" value="<?php echo $search_domain; ?>" type="text"></td>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  <td><input type="submit" class="btn blue_button" 
                    name="submit_domain_form" id="submit_search_button"
                  value="Search" /></td>
                </tr>
              </table></td>
            <td align="center"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="apply_button" style="display:none;">
                <tr>
                  <td><input class="input_field" name="domain_name_url" id="domain_name_url" value="<?php echo $domain_name_url; ?>" type="text"></td>
                  <td>&nbsp;
                  <input name="domain_replace_id" id="domain_replace_id" 
                  value="" type="hidden">
                  <input name="domain_replace_link" id="domain_replace_link" 
                  value="" type="hidden">
                  </td>
                  <td><input type="submit" class="btn blue_button" 
                    name="submit_domain_form" id="submit_replace_button"
                  value="Apply" /></td>
                </tr>
              </table></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                      <td><input type="checkbox" name="status_domain" id="status_domain" <?php if($status_domain){?> checked <?php } ?>>&nbsp;Include inactive campaigns in search.</td>
                      <td>&nbsp;</td>
                      <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>

        </table>     
</form>
```

now I am trying to make a common validation form like this...

```
function primalValidate()
{
    var action = document.forms["m_domain"]["submit_domain_form"].value;
    if(action=="Search")
    {
        //validation condition 1;
        //return false;
    }
    else if(action=="Apply")
    {
        //validation condition 2;
        //return false;
    }

}
```

but the problem is none of the validation condition is working....

when I am trying to alert the value of action, i.e.

`alert(action);` i am getting blank alert

These are the two submit buttons in the form

```
<input type="submit" class="btn blue_button" 
                        name="submit_domain_form" id="submit_search_button"
                      value="Search" />

<input type="submit" class="btn blue_button" 
                        name="submit_domain_form" id="submit_replace_button"
                      value="Apply" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
var action = $("input[type=submit]:focus").val();;
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/rmytrc9u/)

And if you want it by submit button name then try,

```
var action = $("input[name=submit_domain_form]:focus").val();
```

Try it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/rmytrc9u/1/)

Also, if you use enter key to submit then both the above will alert `undefined`. For this, you need some logic according to your HTML design like,

```
if(action==undefined){
    action=$('*:focus').closest('table').find(':submit').val();
    // you can use name=submit_domain_form instead of :submit as used in second updated answer
}
```

See [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/rmytrc9u/2/)

Comment: i need to fetch it by name not id

Comment: but one more thing, if someone doesn't click the submit button, but press enter when the focus is on a textbox, will this code work??

Comment: hello, are u there bro?

Comment: @Saswat No, it wil not work on using enter key. Try my third updated answer.

Comment: [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721724/jquery-how-to-get-which-button-was-clicked-upon-form-submission). On submit of form you can get value of the button which submitted the form.

Comment: @RohanKumar,,,, can you be free for some time?, let me test and if i get some glitch then i can ask you for help...