# Check what exatly button clicked, when multiple buttons with the same selector on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have a two buttons with the same selector class. When I do this:

```
$('.my_button').click(function() {
    console.log(1);
});
```

, and then click on the button it log `1` two times, like I clicked both buttons instead single. So my question is: There exists some way in JS to get only that button what I clicked, without assign unique selector like `id`. I am newbien in JS, so can somebody explain me? I found related issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721724/jquery-how-to-get-which-button-was-clicked-upon-form-submission). Thanks!

Edit:

I make buttons a little bit different. And yes, it returns only single button, but why click trigger works two times. Console log log two times.

Comment: why don't you use id instead of class

Comment: @Optimus, I redeclare Symfony2 form theming, and for some reasons I cant override id, but I can append class to button theme.

Comment: can you add name property to this button

Comment: is there any difference between this two button like value, name or anything

Comment: @Optimus, no they identical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<button class="my_button">Content1</button>
<button class="my_button">Content2</button>

<script>
$( ".my_button" ).click(function( event ) {
console.log(1);
});
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nt9ryeyr/5/

Comment: ahahahhah, I still get two results

Comment: this print on the console 1 only once

Comment: I think I didn't catch what exactly you want to do.
Do you want to print a diferent while clicking on each of your buttons with the same class?

Answer (score 4):

Every event listener receives the event, which carries the event target. Try the below example.

```
$('.my_button').click(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    console.log(e.currentTarget);
    console.log($(e.currentTarget));
});
```

Comment: it return two objects, for first and second button.

Answer (score 3):

use `this` inside your function code

```
$('.my_button').on('click',function() {
    var tempContainer=$(this).parent();
    alert($(tempContainer).html());   // you ll see that you are showing the code where exists your clicked button
});
```

Comment: `console.log($(this).attr('class'))` equal to `2 my_button`

Comment: @excluded_once take a look at my update to understand what i m trying to say

Comment: i getting two allerts with html of two buttons

Comment: @excluded_once use this code with 'live' or 'on' . Now it will works,

Iedited my answer

Comment: I cant get why click works two times. It console log two times content of the same button.

Answer (score 3):

Assign different id to your buttons

```js
$(".my_button").on("click",function(){
  console.log($(this).attr("id"))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" class="my_button" id="test" value="Test"/>
<input type="button" class="my_button" id="test2" value="Test-2"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".p").click(function(e){
        alert($(e.currentTarget).attr("value"));//button text on which you clicked
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type='button' class="p" value='test'/>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

if your html is like this

```
<button class="my_button">Test</button>
<button class="my_button">Test1</button>
```

then use this script

```
$('.my_button').click(function() {
if(this.innerHTML ==="Test")
    console.log(1);
else
console.log(2);
});
```

or if your html is like this

```
<input type="button" class="my_button" value="Test"/>
<input type="button" class="my_button" value="Test1"/>
```

then use this script

```
$('.my_button').click(function() {
if($(this).val() ==="Test")
    console.log(1);
else
console.log(2);
});
```