# jQuery .on not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've seen this appear in a lot of places; however, after several hours, I still can't figure this simple thing out. Could someone verify my syntax is correct here?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#login-form").on('submit', "#logout-btn", function() {
       alert("The logout button was clicked.");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="login-form">
            <input placeholder="Username" id="formUsr" required>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="formPwd" required>

            <input id="logout-btn" type="submit" value="Login">
            <input id="login-btn" type="submit" value="Logout">
</form><!-- login form -->
```

Comment: try on('click', ... instead

Comment: try `$("#login-form").on('submit', function()` instead of `$("#login-form").on('submit', "#logout-btn", function()`

Comment: @PranavCBalan I think he's using the `selector` argument of [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) in order to only fire the event when the `#logout-btn` is clicked, so I'm not sure that's the problem.

Comment: @NobleMushtak : then he should use `click` event

Comment: Hi, so click didn't work. $("#login-form").on('submit', function() works however I want to specify the logout button

Comment: `$("#logout-btn").click(function(){`

Comment: No, the solution is more complicated than just `.submit()` or `.click()`. Go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721724/jquery-how-to-get-which-button-was-clicked-upon-form-submission) for a temporary explanation.

Comment: I hope you've realized that the values for the buttons are swapped aswell, the **Login** button has `id="btn-logout"` and the other way around. Hopefully this is not what you've spent hours on...

Comment: Do you have multiple login buttons that'd require not just referring to it directly?

Comment: The login button that you're delegating the event to does not have a submit action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `submit` event is triggered when a `submit` button is clicked, and there could be more than one, a `button` element without `type="button|reset"` is clicked. It can also be triggered by the `Enter` key.

You can use this to determine if the logout button was clicked. However, for form submission purposes, the `submit` event is by far the most reliable.:

```
$("#logout-btn").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //prevents default action.
    alert("The logout button was clicked.");
});
```

```js
$(function() {
    $("#logout-btn").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //prevents default action.
        alert("The logout button was clicked.");
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="login-form">
    <input placeholder="Username" id="formUsr" required/>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="formPwd" required/>

    <input id="login-btn" type="submit" value="Login"/>
    <input id="logout-btn" type="submit" value="Logout"/>
</form><!-- login form -->
```

Another approach:

```js
$(function() {
    $(':submit').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if( $(this).is('#login-btn') ) {
            alert('login-btn clicked');
        } else if( $(this).is('#logout-btn') ) {
            alert('logout-btn clicked');
        } else {
            alert('some other submit button clicked');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <form id="login-form">
        <input placeholder="Username" id="formUsr" required/>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="formPwd" required/>

        <input id="login-btn" type="submit" value="Login"/>
        <input id="logout-btn" type="submit" value="Logout"/>
    </form><!-- login form -->
```

Comment: No luck with preventDefault()

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: The code snippet above didn't work - using preventDefault didn't work.

Comment: Please take a look at the demo I just added.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this:

```
$("#login-form").submit(function() {
   alert("The logout button was clicked.");
});
```

Comment: This brings the alert but i want to specify the logout button only

Comment: Why there's a login and logout button there?

Comment: I'm hiding to showing one dependent or current logged in/out status. Theres some class hide code there but i didn't show here so as to keep problem clear ;-)

Comment: You should not use submit event for  logout because there's no need to get info. from user's input

Answer (score 0):

Store the value of the last clicked button and in the `.submit()` event, make sure the last clicked button was the logout button. This works because the `.click()` event is fired before the `.submit()` event:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    //The logout button:
    var logoutButton = $("#logout-btn");
    //This variable holds the button in #login-form that the user last clicked:
    var lastClicked = null;
    //When the user clicks a button in #login-form, set it equal to lastClicked:
    $("#login-form input[type=submit]").click(function() {
        lastClicked = $(this);
    });
    //When the form is submitted, if it was the logout button, call the alert:
    $("#login-form").on('submit', function() {
       if (lastClicked.is(logoutButton)) {
           alert("The logout button was clicked.");
       }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="login-form">
            <input placeholder="Username" id="formUsr" required>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="formPwd" required>

            <input id="login-btn" type="submit" value="Login">
            <input id="logout-btn" type="submit" value="Logout">
</form><!-- login form -->
```

Comment: This works however seems really complicated. I would have thought this is a really simple thing to do. I understand whats happening. If i use click instead of submit that doesn't help either.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is rather complicated, but I don't think the DOM provides any easy way to do this. This is simply how JavaScript is. :(

Answer (score 0):

you have two submit button in your form, you can detrmine which was clicked like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#login-form input[type=submit]").click(function() {
    var clickedId = $(this).attr('id');
    if(clickedId=="logout-btn")
      alert("The logout button was clicked.");
    else if(clickedId=="login-btn")
    alert("The login button was clicked.");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

*Note that your **Login** button has the ID of the logout button and the other way around.*

I'm gonna add an alternative to Peters answer, just for the sake of having an alternative.

**Using `onclick` in the markup**

```js
function logOutClicked() {
  alert("Logout button clicked!");
  return true;
}
```

```html
<form id="login-form">
  <input placeholder="Username" id="formUsr" required>
  <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="formPwd" required>
  <input id="login-btn" type="submit" value="Login">
  <input id="logout-btn" type="submit" onclick="return logOutClicked();" value="Logout">
</form>
```

**Using `.bind()`**
Since we have a linear compilation of JavaScript, the first event that will be bound to the logout button in this case is the click event.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#logout-btn').bind('click', function() {
    alert('Logout clicked click');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="login-form">
  <input placeholder="Username" id="formUsr" required>
  <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="formPwd" required>
  <input id="login-btn" type="submit" value="Login">
  <input id="logout-btn" type="submit" onclick="return logOutClicked();" value="Logout">
</form>
```