# $_POST['aggInf'] empty on form submitting

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I'm trying to submit a form with [jquery from plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) With multiple submits, but i can't get the value from the `$_POST['aggInf']` in php, i can get it in js.

My form:

`<form action="#" method="post" id="gestioneProfilo">`

My inputs:

`<input name="aggInf" type="submit" value="Upload" class="upload">
 <input name="aggInfAnn" type="submit" value="Annulla" id="cancel">`

If i try `onsubmit='alert($(this).serialize()); return false;'` on the from i always get this in return:

[image: alert error]

On the js side i used [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721724/jquery-how-to-get-which-button-was-clicked-upon-form-submission) and it works fine, if i try a `console.log()` command i get the correct `value`.
If i try a `var_dump()` command i only get all the other input and textboxes values. How do i fix this?

Full form html:

```
    <form action="#" method="post" id="gestioneProfilo">

        <!-- Scelta avatar -->
        <div id="sceltaAvatar">

            <!-- Profilo -->
            <div id="perAvatar">
                <h1>Scelta dell'Avatar</h1>
                <p>Carica dal tuo pc o dal web una tua immagine di profilo</p>
                <!-- <input type="hidden" name="immP"> -->
            </div>

            <!-- Copertina -->
            <div id="perCopertina">
                <h1>Scelta della copertina</h1>
                <p>Carica dal tuo pc o dal web una tua immagine di copertina</p>
                <!-- <input type="hidden" name="immC"> -->
            </div>

            <!-- Info generali -->
            <div id="altreInfo">
                <div>

                    <!-- informazioni -->
                    <h1>Informazioni</h1>
                    <textarea placeholder="Cosa fai nella vita? Scrivi una breve descrizione su di te" name="bio" id="bio"><?php get_stuff('bio', TRUE, TRUE) ?></textarea>
                </div>
                <div id="due">
                    <div>

                        <!-- Sito -->
                        <h1>Sito</h1>
                        <textarea placeholder="Il tuo sito" name="sito" id="sito"><?php get_stuff('sito', TRUE, TRUE) ?></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div>

                        <!-- Posizione -->
                        <h1>Posizione</h1>
                        <textarea placeholder="Da dove vieni?" name="pos" id="pos"><?php get_stuff('pos', TRUE, TRUE) ?></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Torna indietro -->
            <input name="aggInf" type="submit" value="Upload" class="upload">
            <input name="aggInfAnn" type="submit" value="Annulla" id="cancel">
        </div>
    </form>
    <?php include_once 'lightbox.php' ?>
```

js:

```
$('#gestioneProfilo').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var
        val = $("input[type=submit][clicked=true]").val(),
        pop = $(this);

    console.log(val);
    // it works, if i press upload it prints upload, if i press annulla it prints annulla

    if (val == "Upload") {
        $(this).ajaxSubmit({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "lib/ajax.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: pop.serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                //stuff
            }
        });
    }else{
        cambiaA("#perCommentare", "#gestioneProfilo", "ritorna");
    };
});

$(document).on('click', '#gestioneProfilo input[type=submit]', function() {
    $("input[type=submit]",
    $(this).parents("#gestioneProfilo")).removeAttr("clicked");
    $(this).attr("clicked", "true");
});
```

php:

```
if (isset($_POST['aggInf'])) {

    update_info();

    $return_data['immP'] = get_stuff('immP');
    $return_data['immC'] = get_stuff('immC');
    $return_data['bio']  = get_stuff('bio');
    $return_data['sito'] = get_stuff('sito', FALSE, TRUE);
    $return_data['pos']  = get_stuff('pos');
    echo json_encode($return_data);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Show your full HTML please. Especially the full `<form>` tag.

Comment: probably because the submit doesn't hold the name attribute for it. Error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php will tell you if it is or not. `<input name="aggInfAnn" type="submit" value="Annulla" id="cancel">` should read as `<input name="aggInfAnn" type="submit" value="Annulla" id="cancel" name="submit">` or whatever input it's supposed to be (only you know that). In a nutshell, there is no `name="submit"` anywhere in your "posted" code.

Comment: And also, it is better to use `<input type="hidden">` instead.

Comment: That's not how `$_POST` works in PHP - ideally you need to supply a PHP script to the forms `action` event and the elements need to have a `name` value for the post method to pick up the values.

Comment: *"but i can't get the value from the $_POST['submit'] in php"* - there is nothing in your (now edited) question to support your question.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, sorry i meant `aggInf`, i edited it now, so it should be ok

Comment: @user3847141 please post your PHP also, it could be something in there. and more JS

Comment: @user3847141 I reopened the question. However this `var` there is nothing after that, so I don't know what you're trying to do here, or to assign something to it. Remove it and see if it works.

Comment: @Fred-ii- nothing changes, i used it to declare the `val` and `pop` variables