# jQuery continue form submission with selected submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, coffeescript

I'm intercepting the submission of a form with jQuery and validating a few things before continuing submission. The problem is that there are multiple submit buttons with different actions on the page and when I try to call `form.submit()` after validation the `name` tag of the submit button is lost / not sent in the request-params.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="publish" value="Publish">
<input type="submit" name="draft" value="Save as draft">
```

and in the coffeescript code I'm intercepting form submission with:

```
$('#foo-form').submit (e) ->
  e.preventDefault()
  form = this

  # DO WORK...
  # A callback eventually calls form.submit()
```

I'd like to somehow store which button was clicked and pass it on to `form.submit()`.

Comment: possible duplicate, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5721762/3173842

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `click` event handler to each submit button that adds (or updates) a hidden input with the values.

```
function store_submit_value (ev) {
    var $frm = jQuery(this.form);
    var $input = $frm.find("input.submit_value");
    if (!$input.length) {
        $input = jQuery("<input />")
            .attr("type", "hidden")
            .addClass("submit_value")
            .appendTo($frm);
    }
    $input.attr("name", this.name).val(this.value);
}

jQuery("#foo-form").on("click", 'input[type="submit"]', store_submit_value);
```