# Javascript onsubmit with form with multiple submits buttons

Tags: javascript

I have a form with two submits buttons, one called 'display' and the other called 'disenrol'.  The display submit doesn't need confirmation whereas the other does.  Originally I was going to use

```
onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to remove the modules?');"
```

But of course that won't work because it reacts to both of the submits.  Is there a way I can specify which submit it should worth with?  (I'm quite new to javascript so please be gentle with me)

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use onsubmit() show a confirmation with multiple submit buttons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18038085/how-to-use-onsubmit-show-a-confirmation-with-multiple-submit-buttons)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to remove the modules?');" value="submit1" />
```

Comment: Just FYI, this won't work if the user performs the submission without using the mouse, e.g., presses Enter.

Comment: it is asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066162/how-can-i-get-the-button-that-caused-the-submit-from-the-form-submit-event