# Change form action based on submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have many forms like the following on the page. Now I want change the form action based on which submit button the user clicked (and of course submit the form)

```
<form action="/shop/products.php" data-ajax="false" method="post">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">

        <input name="submit" class="obutn" type="submit" value="Order" />
        <input name="submit" class="oEbutn" type="submit" value="Extras" />

    </div>
</form>
```

I tried with

```
$(".obtn").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().attr("action", "/shop/products.php");     
});
$(".oEbtn").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().attr("action", "/shop/extras.php");       
});
```

but the form is always submited to products.php. Can you tell me what's wrong?

Comment: You've misspelt the class names.

Comment: You could use .closest('form') instead of the two parent() selectors to clean it up a bit

Comment: Instead of setting the ```action``` attribute on the form itself, consider setting ```formaction``` attribute on each individual ```input``` element.

Docs: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.submit.html#input.submit.attrs.formaction

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two typos:

- `obtn` instead of `obutn`
- `oEbtn` instead of `oEbutn`

Another suggestion is to use `closest("form")` to get the form that contains the clicked button.

```
$(".obutn").click(function() {
    $(this).closest("form").attr("action", "/shop/products.php");     
});
$(".oEbutn").click(function() {
    $(this).closest("form").attr("action", "/shop/extras.php");       
});

$("form").on("submit", function () {
    alert($(this).attr("action"));
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7Vk7e/)

Answer (score 13):

Instead of setting the `action` attribute on the form itself, consider setting `formaction` attribute on each individual `input` element.

Docs: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.submit.html#input.submit.attrs.formaction

```
<form data-ajax="false" method="post">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <input formaction="/shop/products.php" 
               name="submit" class="obutn" type="submit" value="Order" />
        <input formaction="/shop/extras.php" 
               name="submit" class="oEbutn" type="submit" value="Extras" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You can use `formaction` with `<button>`s too: `<button form="FORM_ID" formaction="/my/new/action">save</button>`

Answer (score 2):

Capture the submit event and determine which button was clicked.  From that, you can change the action of the form.

Here's a link on how to do that.

[How can I get the button that caused the submit from the form submit event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066162/how-can-i-get-the-button-that-caused-the-submit-from-the-form-submit-event)

Answer (score 1):

Also, don't give the form the action until the click happens at all, it is superfluous.

```
<form data-ajax="false" method="post">
   <div data-role="fieldcontain">

        <input name="submit" class="obutn" type="submit" value="Order" />
        <input name="submit" class="oEbutn" type="submit" value="Extras" />

    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you try it out with a switch instead? Something like:

```
<input name="submit" id = "1" class="obutn" type="submit" value="Order" />
<input name="submit" id = "2" class="oEbutn" type="submit" value="Extras" />
```

And then in JavaScript we have:

```
//param: The Id attr of the button that was clicked
function postTo(id){
  switch(id){
   case 1: postProducts();
           break;
   case 2: postExtras();
           break;

   default: //Do something else 

  }
}
```

Just an idea. Haven´t tested that yet, but maybe it could be helpful. I hope so.

Comment: No prob. Glad you found a solution :)