# Passing input to url with get method in form in laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5, parameter-passing

I want to pass my search input to laravel 5.1 like this

localhost:8000/search/{searchtext}

but right now it send data with this method

localhost:8000/search?search='searchtext'

```
            <form action="search" method="get" class="form-wrapper">

            <input type="text"  NAME="query" id="search" placeholder="جستجو ..."  required>
            {{--<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{!! csrf_token() !!}">--}}
            <input type="submit" value="بررسی" id="submit">


        </form>
```

Can you give me a solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

Change the action attribute of the form in the onSubmit event, you have to use javascript. The exact code depends if you are using a library like jQuery or plain Javascript.
Here a useful link:
[Change form action based on submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17661645/change-form-action-based-on-submit-button)

Comment: I think it's possible in laravel 5.1 because we can do that in laravel 4 but in this version ,I don't know how I can do that.

Comment: can you give an example of the code you used in laravel 4?