# Identify which button submitted a form

Tags: javascript, button

Given the following form:

```
<form action method="post" onsubmit="func(this)">
    <button type="submit" value="prev"  >prev</button>
    <button type="submit" value="next"  >next</button>
    <button type="submit" value="submit">submit</button>
    <button type="reset"  value="reset" >reset</button>
</form>
```

Within `func()`, how to identify which button submitted the form?

Comment: what javascript function?

Comment: Java script function is used to validate the fields based on the button clicked. if button clicked is next then different validation etc

Comment: js function or event can be fired and then you can identify which button is pressed

Comment: Can you show what you try so far ? Edit the question.

Comment: `<form action="call java script functions" method="get">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
  <button type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button>
</form>`

Comment: And still there's no js code in example.

Comment: Shortened title while preserving meaning, merged actual code with described code to create working example, rephrased question succinctly

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066162/how-can-i-get-the-button-that-caused-the-submit-from-the-form-submit-event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. You can attach click event to each button and take action. This is cleanest way.

```
<button onclick="alert('You are clicking on me');">Reset</button>
```

Instead of alert insert your custom function. You can make it more robust by not using inline javascript.
In those functions you can choose if you want to submit form or not by preventing or passing default event. Like `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: Thanks @Mateusz, its working fine. I used the solution suggested by you.

Comment: @ashu then you can accept answer, no need to comment ;-)