# Multiple buttons in Bootstrap validator form

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I have a simple form with multiple submit buttons. How do I change the java script to see, which button is clicked. Thanks

```
<form class="contact" role="form" data-toggle="validator" id="testform">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputName" class="control-label">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" name="inputName" placeholder="Cina Saffary" required>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="save1" value="save1">save1</button>
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="save2" value="save2">save2</button>
    </div>
</form>


$('#testform').validator().on('submit', function (e) { (e.isDefaultPrevented()) { 
  alert("failure!"); 
} else { 
  // if save1 clicked, alert("save1 was clicked"); 
  // if save2 clicked, alert("save2 was clicked"); 
} 
});
```

Comment: Look at [this](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object) site for some hints.

Answer (score 0):

You can get button value like this:

```
var val = $("button[type=submit][clicked=true]").val();
```

And you need to add one more event for button also

```
 $("form button[type=submit]").click(function() {
    $("button[type=submit]", $(this).parents("form")).removeAttr("clicked");
    $(this).attr("clicked", "true");
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/L4xq4gwh/)

Reference: [How can I get the button that caused the submit from the form submit event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066162/how-can-i-get-the-button-that-caused-the-submit-from-the-form-submit-event)