# Codeigniter PHP submit post

Tags: php, html, forms, codeigniter

i have a simple form using codeigniter and there is a submit button:

```
<?php echo form_open('myController/add'); ?>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="myInput" value='abc'>
<button type="submit" name="Submit">Save</button>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

but it doesn't contain Submit when i run this code:

```
function add(){
  print_r($_POST);
}
```

here is the result:

```
Array ( [myInput] => abc )
```

i think the result should be like this:

```
Array ( [myInput] => abc [Submit] =>)
```

please help.. thank you.

Comment: try `<input type="submit" name="submit"/>`

Comment: How are you submitting the form? By hitting the "Save" button or hitting the `Enter` key while typing in the text field?

Comment: Is there any JavaScript that intercepts the form submission?

Comment: @shyammakwana.me that is not good advice

Comment: @Phil I know but I can't see any other error or typos. so just a try.

Comment: Demo showing that it *should* work just fine here ~ https://jsfiddle.net/2gdfuzd4/. I suspect there's some JavaScript messing with the form submission

Comment: Here's an example showing how a JavaScript form submission will omit the button name / value pair ~ https://jsfiddle.net/2gdfuzd4/2/

Comment: @shyammakwana.me i tried both button and input but nothing.

Comment: @Phil i dont have any javascript in this form. yeah, it work just fine in jsfiddle and still i dont know ahy it doesnt work on my project

Comment: @oka can you be certain there's no JS involved? Try disabling JavaScript in your browser (just google how to if you don't know) and try again

Comment: @Phil thankyou, it works when i disabled javascript. so how prevent this issue while i need to enable javascript

Comment: @oka find the JavaScript that's intercepting your form submission and remove / alter it. This might help ~ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066162/how-can-i-get-the-button-that-caused-the-submit-from-the-form-submit-event

Comment: @phil i actually getting confused, i think i dont have any javascript form submission, i mean, yes right there is a javascript but i dont use 
$("form").submit(function() { } ); or something like document.forms["myform"].submit();

Comment: It's impossible to help you any further. Check for **any** JS you're including on that page. Could be a 3rd party form validation script or something like that

Comment: @Phil here is my own javascript https://pastebin.com/gbTSReNy , and the other javascript is from bootstrap, jquey, etc

Comment: It's the `etc` I'd worry about

Comment: what about this?

custom.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: this.submit is not a function
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (custom.min.js:1)
    at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLFormElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)

Answer (score 0):

Per Mozilla's documentation for the button element, you can have a value attribute. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

This means you could just do this:

```
<button type="submit" name="Submit" value="something">Save</button>
```

and then you would have:

```
$_POST['Submit'] = "something";
```

BUT in your question it looks like you want the Submit key to be present, even if there is no value, and I don't think that's going to work. I do believe you will have to have something as a value in order for the key to be present.

Comment: *"I don't think that's going to work"* <- that's where you're wrong. A *named* button of type *submit* will send whatever its `value` property is, even if the attribute is not set in which case it will send an empty string

Comment: Well, I don't know if it's appropriate to change my answer, and you are probably right (or you wouldn't have said I was wrong). I think I was thinking about the behavior of jQuery ajax posts where the value is empty.

Answer (score 0):

When you start the project with codeigniter framework then you need to insert data into database.  I think you need to tyr this code for get data 'name' => $this->input->post('name').

**For example:**

```
class Controller extends CI_Controller {
function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('Mymodel');
}
public function user_registration(){
$data = array('name' => $this->input->post('name'),'email' => $this->input->post('email'),'password' => $this->input->post('pwd'));
$this->Mymodel->UserRegistration($data);
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

use

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Save">
```

instead of

```
<button type="submit" name="Submit">Save</button>
```

because `$_post` get value of input

but you can also get its value using its `name`

like

```
$formSubmit = $this->input->post('Submit');
echo $formSubmit;
```

Comment: This gets a downvote until you can explain just why this might make any difference

Comment: As you can see here, a named submit `<button>` works just fine ~ https://jsfiddle.net/2gdfuzd4/

Comment: *"`<button>` is a not get as a input*" <- this is completely incorrect

Comment: Yes explain why this might make any difference @Bhargav??

Comment: ask google for that i give my answer if questioner have any doubt than i explain