# How to detect submit form button was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've two button on submit form.

**1. Add to Cart Button**

**2. Buy Now Button**

I need to add disable class if the button was clicked,

```
submitForm: function (form) {
        var addToCartButton, buyNowButton, self = this;

        if (form.has('input[type="file"]').length && form.find('input[type="file"]').val() !== '') {
            self.element.off('submit');
            // disable 'Add to Cart' button

            addToCartButton = $(form).find(this.options.addToCartButtonSelector);
            buyNowButton = $(form).find(this.options.buyNowButtonSelector);

            if(addToCartButton){
                addToCartButton.prop('disabled', true);
                addToCartButton.addClass(this.options.addToCartButtonDisabledClass);
            }else if(buyNowButton){
                buyNowButton.prop('disabled', true);
                buyNowButton.addClass(this.options.buyNowButtonDisabledClass);
            }


            form.submit();
        } else {
            self.ajaxSubmit(form);
        }
    },
```

Comment: `<input type="submit" onclick="this.disabled=true">`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the button that caused the submit from the form submit event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066162/how-can-i-get-the-button-that-caused-the-submit-from-the-form-submit-event) -> You can use `document.activeElement` inside the vent handler to find out, which button was used to trigger the form submit (or if any of those buttons was used at all, because a form submit may also be triggered by pressing enter inside a text-field)

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this (JQuery):

```
          $(".classNameOfButton").click(function(){functionName(this)});
```

Comment: Please describe in more detail why this might be solution.

Answer (score 0):

Pure Javascript, here you go :)

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const button = document.querySelector("button");

  button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.target.disabled = true
  }) 
});
```

1. wait for DOM content to get loaded (probably not necessary in your case as it will be part of larger codebase
2. get button element you need
3. addEventListener for `click` to that element
4. set disabled to `true`

About `event.target`

https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Event/target

Codepen:

https://codepen.io/pen/

Answer (score 0):

JS:

```
// Disable default Event (Browser reloading..)
const formElement = document.getElementByID("formID");
formElement.addEventListener("submit", () => {
```

event.preventDefault();
});

```
const button1 = document.getElementByID("button1");
button1.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
 // do something...
     e.target.classList.add("disabled");
});


const button2 = document.getElementByID("button2");
button2.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
 // do something...
     e.target.classList.add("disabled");
});
```

1. Prevent Default Action of a form submit button (reload site)
2. get both buttons and attach an "click" event listener
3. If clicked add "disabled" class