# Unable to get button value/attribute in jquery using php loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm working on "like" and "dislike" module in jQuery with PHP,And I'm facing these two problems:

1. Right now unable to get `id` of button (like=1, dislike=0)
2. Query showing correct result but how to display ajax response under "like dislike" section ?

Here is my code, following code inside foreach loop:

```
<?php foreach // ?>
 <form class="form-horizontals1" method="post" >
                <input type="hidden"  id="ReviewId" name="ReviewId" value="<?php echo $rev->id;?>">
                
             <button class="likebutn_r" id="show<?php echo "1";?>"  type="submit"><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/assets/img/thumb.png" height="24" width="24"></button>
             <label class="lilkcount">10(dynamic) </label>
            
            <button class="likebutn_r" id="shows<?php echo "0";?>"  type="submit"><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/assets/img/thumbdown.png" height="24" width="24"></button>
             <label class="lilkcount">5(dynamic)</label>
        <div id="counter"></div>
        </form>
    <?php end foreach // ?> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //likebutn_r
        $('.form-horizontals1').submit(function(e){
            
var ids = $(this).attr('ids');
 console.log(ids);          
        alert($(this).attr("id"));  
                e.preventDefault(); 
 $.ajax({
 url:'<?php echo base_url();?>main/AddVote',
 type:"post",
 data:new FormData(this),
 //dataType: 'json',
 processData:false,
 contentType:false,
 cache:false,
 async:false,
 success: function(data){
     console.log(data);
     alert(data);
    $('#counter').html(data); 
 }
 
 });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is my **controller code**, please tell me how I can get "like dislike" value in script and how I can show result in views ?

```
function AddVote()
    {
        $ReviewId=$_POST['ReviewId'];
        $vote=$_POST['vote'];
        echo $result['TotalUpVotes'] = $this->M_main->CountSubmittedCoinVote($ReviewId,$vote);
        echo $result['TotalDownVotes'] = $this->M_main->CountSubmittedDownVotes($ReviewId,$vote);
    }
```

Comment: 1) you're getting `.attr("ids")` but your html has `id=..` (not `ids`) on the buttons - not that that matters because 2) your `submit` event is on `.form-horizontls1` so `this` is the form, not the button 3) it's possible to submit a form without clicking a button.  If you don't want the form submit (e.preventDefault) then cancel all form submits and handle button `click`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery: how to get which button was clicked upon form submission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721724/jquery-how-to-get-which-button-was-clicked-upon-form-submission)

Comment: Or: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066162/how-can-i-get-the-button-that-caused-the-submit-from-the-form-submit-event  - `event.submittedVia` seems to be the solution there but can't see it on MDN (with a quick look)

Comment: IDs must be unique within an HTML document. Your loop would still create `id="show1"`and `id="shows0"` multiple times, as soon as that loop iterates for more than one single time.

Answer (score 0):

1. First, move the form ouside the loop.

   ```
    <form class="form-horizontals1" method="post" >
    <?php foreach // ?>
    <div class="my-rev-container js-rev-container">
    ...
    </div>
    <?php end foreach // ?>
    </form>
   ```
2. Add a class to the inputs, you whould access with

   ```
    <input type="hidden" class="js-form__rev" id="ReviewId" name="ReviewId" value="<?php echo $rev->id;?>">
   ```
3. Finaly access them

   ```
    $('.form-horizontals1').submit(function(e){
    var ids = $(this).find(".js-form__rev");
    console.log(ids);
   ```